# Telerik UI server side sorting

Tags: c#, sorting, model-view-controller, telerik

I use server side sorting and i send sort values in next format:

```
 sort[0][field]:dsdsd
 sort[0][dir]:asc
```

And I want to receive in controller this values as

```
  List<Sort>
```

where

```
public class Sort
{
public string field{get;set;}
public string dir{get;set;
}
```

My action

```
public ActionResult Data(Requestdata data){

}
```

where

```
public class RequestData
{
public List<Sort> Sort{get;set;}
}
```

But in list of the Sorts I receive only count of sorts but without any values.

```
[{dir=null,field=null}, {dir=null,field=null} ]
```

What I do wrong?

Comment: Can you show your front end markup for the Telerik Control?

Comment: @Greg , I use standard settings for datasource

Comment: Okay, you don't do any changes when you instantiate the Telerik extension method from the Razor syntax?

Comment: When I added in grid configuration sortable: {    mode: "multiple"   } and serverSorting: true, my request started to send sort values as additional parameter, but I can't receive this values on server side. And I use POST as type of request.

Comment: http://www.telerik.com/sfimages/default-source/blogs/windows-live-writer-ask-kendo-ui--server-sorting-with-webapi_8eb7-image_thumb_5-png-png   my parameters sended like on this picture

Answer (score 0):

Using $.aspParam(requestData) solves this problem.